# Palo Alto dropping Global Protect traffic intermittently

Tags: networking, active-directory, group-policy, palo-alto-networks

Everyone, hoping I'm posting to the correct forum, Palo Alto support hasn't been able to solve this yet for me.

Users with Palo Alto Global Protect installed are seeing their packets get denied by the firewall but only intermittently, and only if Global Protect is joined to the domain, and so far only on Windows 10.  It may be happening on Windows 7 as well, not sure.

I should be clear this isn't a thing where Global Protect disconnects.  It remains connected but packets start becoming denied at the firewall.  It shows up in the firewall logs for the Global Protect IP as being denied during that time.  The IP is not showing up on the PA IP Block-List during these times either.  The condition does clear itself after a while and I don't see any events preceding the deny blocks that would point to a cause.  It shows up as traffic getting blocked for a time, sometimes upwards of an hour or so, then mysteriously, as mentioned previously, the condition clears itself and traffic begins flowing normally again.

It isn't related to any GPO (I don't think) because at one point, I disabled the group policy client on the affected machine and still saw intermittent packet blockage.

The issue begins occurring almost immediately after I join the machine to the domain and reboot it.  If I disjoin it from the domain and restart the condition doesn't come back at all.

This is NOT an issue with MacOS machines that are AD bound.

I've tried adjusting the time to see if that could be causing issues, no luck.  What else about a machine's domain relationship would contribute to the issue I'm seeing?

Comment: I have a customer seeing a similar issue. Mac GP clients are seeing packet loss every 10-15 minutes. They have an ipsec, and a Win10 and a MAC client connected at the same time. Only the MAC sees packet loss. We tested 9.0.8 and GP ver 5.1.5. This looks like a bug to me. Ask to have the case escalated.

Comment: Thanks will do.  Can't believe other people aren't seeing the same thing.